# Getting percentage of conversions in Smarty template?

Tags: php, math, smarty

I have two different variables in my smarty template:

{$visitors} - Shows the number of clicks on a link.
{$numitems} - Show the number of signups from the clicks.

I need to get the conversion rate as a percentage which mathematically would be `{$numitems}`/`{$visitors}`*`100`

Does anyone know how to do this in the smarty template system - and limit it to 2 numbers after the decimal point - for example, 3.81

Comment: First did the other question you had get resolved with the if/else issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably take a look at **Math** then.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.math.tpl

Since I don't know if you are using ver 2 or 3 since you never answered that. You can use math and it will work in either.

e.g. 
You can do this.

```
{math assign="$percentage" equation="(x / y) * 100" x=$numitems y=$visitors format="%.2f"}
```

Then you you can use `{$percentage}` to show the amount or do whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this?

```
{($numitems/$visitors*100)|string_format:"%.2f"}
```

Maybe you have to do this in 2 steps:

```
{$x=$numitems/$visitors*100}
{$x|string_format:"%.2f"}
```